# FireStore Query does not return records although there is data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Tried to query DB from  Flutter with following snippet

```
await _firestore.collection('products').get().then((docs) => {
    if (docs.docs.isNotEmpty){
        // do something
    }
});
```

The rules in Firestore are fine as well

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if true; 
        }
    }
}
```

But I donot get any data in response, although there is data here:
[image]

Comment: stopped the app, disconnected from internet and connected back... ran flutter clean and then flutter run, and it worked...

Answer (score 1):

The user proceeded to stop the app and disconnected from the internet.  Then proceed to connect to the internet and ran flutter clean, he then ran the app again and that fixed the issue.